# Is a proper morphism between quasiprojective varieties projective?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification

I'm currently reading Shafarevich's *Basic Algebraic Geometry 1*. In it (page 59), he makes the following definition:

> ...a wider class of maps $f: X \rightarrow Y$ between quasiprojective varieties, namely those that factor as a composite of a closed embedding $\iota: X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n \times Y$ and the projection $p:  \mathbb{P}^n \times Y \rightarrow Y$. Such maps are said to be *proper*.

But this is the definition of a *projective* morphism! (In the sense of [Hartshorne](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01W7), not EGA). Is Shafarevich over-simplifying, using outdated terminology, or using a definition that's in fact equivalent in his context?

In other words, is a proper morphism between quasiprojective varieties automatically projective? I'd like to say that it is, and I have the following germ (hehe) of a proof in my head:

If $X \rightarrow Y$ is a proper morphism of quasiprojective varieties, then in particular it is universally closed, so the base change $\mathbb{P}^n \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n \times Y$ is a closed map. This should be enough, but I'm not sure how to finish (it has something to do with diagonals and graphs being closed which has something to do with separatedness, but this is a condition I've never been very comfortable using).

I think a similar argument shows that a complete quasiprojective variety is projective, by taking a base change along $\mathbb{P}^n \rightarrow k$ and using something about the graph/diagonal being closed.

*I've tagged this proof-verification but I'm not sure that's appropriate: please remove it if you don't think it is*

Comment: Where are you going to get the required closed embedding? For that matter, how do you choose $n$?

Comment: I think $n$ should be the dimension of some projective space where $X$ lives: the closed embedding would be the graph of the immersion of $X$ into this space (or something like that). Is this reasonable?

Comment: But $X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ is not closed...?

Comment: I'm thinking of the diagonal map $X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n \times X$

Comment: Yes, that is closed, because $\mathbb{P}^n$ is separated.

Comment: So does the proof then go through? How does the separatedness imply that the map I mention is closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that $\mathbb{P}^n$ is separated, i.e. the diagonal $\Delta \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^n$ is closed. Choose an (open-in-closed) immersion $j : X \to \mathbb{P}^n$. Then the graph $\Gamma_j = \{ (x, j (x)) : x \in X \} \subseteq X \times \mathbb{P}^n$ is the preimage of $\Delta \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^n$ along the regular map $j \times \mathrm{id} : X \times \mathbb{P}^n \to \mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^n$, so $\Gamma_j \subseteq X \times \mathbb{P}^n$ is also closed.

As you say, the map $f \times \mathrm{id} : X \times \mathbb{P}^n \to Y \times \mathbb{P}^n$ is closed, so $\{ (f (x), j (x)) : x \in X \} \subseteq Y \times \mathbb{P}^n$ is closed. Hence, $(f, j) : X \to Y \times \mathbb{P}^n$ is the required closed immersion, and therefore $X \to Y$ is a projective morphism.