# Shafarevich definition of Proper Morphism

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

In Shafarevich's Algebraic Geometry 1, he defines a proper map between quasiprojective varieties, namely $f: X \to Y$ as a map $f$ that can be factored into the composition of $\iota: X \hookrightarrow\mathbb{P}^n \times Y$, a closed embedding and $\pi: \mathbb{P}^n \times Y \to Y$, a projection.

My definition of a proper map in the sense of topological spaces is that the preimage of compact sets is compact, or an equivalent definition in locally compact and Hausdorff spaces, the map is closed with compact fibers.

My question is how are these definitions related? How could I prove that these are equivalent definitions in the case where $f: X \to Y$ is a regular map of quasiprojective varieties?

In the text, he goes on to say that the preimage of a point is a projective variety, (in particular it will be compact), so since $\iota$ and $\pi$ are closed maps then we have that $f$ is a proper map (in Shafarevich sense) implies that $f$ is a closed map with compact fibers. Is it possible to show the converse?

Relevant post, but a different question: [Is a proper morphism between quasiprojective varieties projective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1424847/is-a-proper-morphism-between-quasiprojective-varieties-projective)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: In the Zariski topology on $\Bbb P^n_R$ for any noetherian ring $R$ and any $n\in\Bbb Z_{\geq 0}$, every subset is compact with the induced topology. So it maybe doesn't make sense to ask to prove that the two definitions are equivalent without making some sort adjustment to the problem. (Maybe ask for topologically proper on analytification if you're over $\Bbb C$?) OTOH, AG-proper is finite type + separated + universally closed, and for a map of Hausdorff spaces where the target is loc. cpct, topologically proper is equivalent to universally closed. So maybe enjoying the analogy is enough.

Comment: I should assert that I am only considering over $\mathbb{C}$ for simplicity sake. So, I should understand AG-proper as a fundamentally different definition that has some parallels with the topological definition when thinking of a Hausdorff topology, but still it is a fundamentally different concept?